# For an odd prime, the hyper-factorial and double-factorial are connected by the relation $H(p-1) \equiv (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}(p-1)!!(\mod{p})$

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

I have so far worked through the proof and stated that:
$$H(p-1) = \prod_{k=1}^{p-1}k^k = \frac{(sf(p-1))^{p-1}}{sf(p-2)}$$
$$=  \frac{(sf(p-1))^{p-1}(p-1)!}{sf(p-1)}$$
$$\equiv \frac{-1}{sf(p-1)} \equiv \frac{-1}{(p-1)!!}$$
by Fermats little theorem, Wilson's theorem and by the fact that $sf(p-1) \equiv (p-1)!! (\mod{p})$.
I am struggling to prove the next part which states:
\begin{equation}
  ((p-1)!!)^{-1}=
    \begin{cases}
      (p-1)!! & \text{if $p \equiv 3\mod 4$}\\
      -(p-1)!! & \text{if $p \equiv 1\mod 4$}\\
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}
Was wondering if someone could please help me clarify what is happening above?
Apparently it has something to do with the following equivalence:
$$((p-1)!!)^2 \equiv \Big(\frac{p-1}{2}!\Big)^2 \equiv (-1)^{\frac{p+1}{2}}(\mod{p})$$ 
but I cannot make the relation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know what *sf* means, but proving the congruences for $(p-1)!!$ is easy. Since $p-1$ is even (I assume $p>2$),
  $$ (p-1)!!=2\cdot 4\dotsb (p-1) = 2^{\frac{p-1}2}\Big(\frac{p-1}2\Big)!. $$
It follows that
  $$ (p-1)!! \equiv (-2)^{\frac{p-1}2} (p-1)(p-2)\dotsb(p-\frac{p-1}2)\pmod p. $$
Multiplying out, you get
  $$ ((p-1)!!)^2 \equiv (-1)^{\frac{p-1}2} 2^{p-1} (p-1)! \equiv (-1)^{\frac{p+1}2} \pmod p $$
by Fermat little theorem and Willson's theorem. This is equivalent to the congruence for $((p-1)!!)^{-1}$ in your question.

Comment: Hi W-t-P, apologies for the confusion - sf means superfactorial. given by $\prod_{k=1}^{n}k!$

Comment: How do we know $((p-1)!!)^{-1}$ has the equivalent congruence of $(-1)^{\frac{p+1}{2}}(\mod{p})$?

Comment: @JohnOmielan: The double factorial $n!!$ is standardly defined as the product of all the integers from $1$ to $n$ that have the same parity \as $n$; see, for instance, [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial]. I hope it clears off all further confusion; otherwise please let me know and I will happily explain.

Comment: @J.Bry: you want to show that $((p-1)!!)^{-1}\equiv (-1)^{\frac{p+1}2}(p-1)!!\pmod p$, and this is equivalent to $((p-1)!!)^2\equiv (-1)^{\frac{p+1}2}\pmod p$. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @W-t-P I've never seen that before. Thanks for the explanation. Various areas of math sometimes redefine notation for their own use, with context indicating what is appropriate. For some reason, it seems number theory does this more than other areas, e.g., $(a,b)$ meaning $\gcd(a,b)$ rather than an ordered pair, and $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$ meaning the Legendre symbol rather than a fraction.

Comment: @J.Bry: Is the solution clear? Have I answered your question?

Comment: @W-t-P: yes, the solution is clear. Thank you.